# Singular noun with the word "difference"

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

There was a sentence in an IELTS book written by Mat Clark:

> Understanding a culture has more implications. Differences in **social
>   background, cultural values and religious belief** might make the
>   discrepancy of foreigners and local inhabitants on some issues
>   indelible.

Differences are at least between two things, for example, two beliefs or two backgrounds.

Shouldn't all the bold words be plural?

Comment: In your last 15 questions you have only accepted 2 answers

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct. You are right that a difference, or a comparison, is between at least two things, but your example is counting the *differences*, not the "things" which have differences. As "differences" is already plural there is no need to pluralise everything else.

A common example is the phrase "*a difference of opinion*". If two people have a difference of opinion then logically there must be two different opinions, there is only *one difference*. If more people were involved, or multiple opinions you might say *either* "*differences* of opinion" *or* "different *opinions*".

Comment: Is it a matter of choice whether to use plural or singular in this paragraph or one of them is only correct?

Comment: @MasihK Your example is a list with 'AND', so there are many differences. If you were suggesting that there would be only 1 difference from that list, you'd use OR.